# Is there any property of render to scroll linchart horizontaly by more than 1 point?

Tags: android, achartengine, linechart

When we scroll the chart in horizontal direction we scroll it by one point is there any render property to make chart scroll by more than one point.

i.e. when we scroll wee should directly shift by more than 1 point.

(I am using achartengine to draw line chart)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can add PanListener to your GraphicalView and handle it from there

```
GraphicalView mChartView;
mChartView.addPanListener(mPanListener);
.......
PanListener mPanListener = new PanListener() {

    @Override
    public void panApplied() {
          //manage scrolling option here
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks Ashru but i had handled that events and it is very complicated to set xmin each time on forward and reverse scroll.